# how can I show an android modeless PopupWindow?

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow

I expected PopupWindow in Android act sort of like a UIPopoverController in iOS.  For those who are not familiar with iOS - a UIPopoverController allows to display a modeless view - and if you touch outside it - it is dismissed.  So I expected that when I create a PopupWindow in android and touch outside it - it should be dismissed automatically.  However PopupWindow is a s modal as a regular dialog.  So how do you create a modeless PopupWindow? - the system apparently provides the way to do it - this is just not as trivial as I thought.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `Dialog` and `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)`

Comment: I'm here because I use a PopupWindow and I write automated tests. Dialog.dismiss() is asynchronous (because Java), so I can't cleanly test Dialogs, so I always must use PopupWindow.